# How to view the raw request of HTTPoison

Tags: elixir

I am trying to submit this form using HTTPoison

https://gist.github.com/shankardevy/6728d63eb528b3cb223a

with the below code:

```
HTTPoison.post!(url,{:multipart, [{"username", "user"}, {"password", "pass"}]})
```

However, the resulting page gives "invalid authentication". But when I try to login using the same credentials using browser, it works.

So I was wondering if I can see the raw http request by HTTPoison so that I can compare it with the raw request from browser.

Comment: As an alternative solution, [`Tesla.Middleware.Logger`](https://hexdocs.pm/tesla/Tesla.Middleware.Logger.html) is great for this.

Answer (score 11):

If you just want to see the request, how about accessing `http://httpbin.org`? It echoes back the requested information.

```
iex(1)> IO.puts HTTPoison.post!("http://httpbin.org/post",{:multipart, [{"username", "user"}, {"password", "pass"}]}).body
```

`HTTPoison` uses `hackney` as backend, and I have file-uploading example using `hackney` in the following (Though it's somewhat different from your example, I'm posting it for your reference, as I previously struggled on finding examples about multipart).

https://github.com/parroty/excoveralls/blob/master/lib/excoveralls/poster.ex

Is there any special reason to use multipart for just sending user/password parameter by the way?

Comment: thanks @parroty. I tried as per your suggestion both using `:hackney` and `HTTPoison` but the response says my credentials are wrong while they work fine with browser. So I am looking to actually see the raw request by HTTPoison rather than the json formatted httpbin's response to debug. on another note, I have no control over changing the form and so had to use 'multipart' request because that is what the remote server expects.

Comment: Sorry I don't know the answer for the raw request part, but if you want to compare it with browser, it might be easier to write a simple local server to receive the requests from both sides, rather than analyzing raw request (like through packet capturing, etc.). Just in case, "uri" parameter in the form is also specified?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the awesome [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) tool to create a proxy for your requests, e.g.

`$ ngrok example.com 8080`

will spit out an URL like http://abcd1234.ngrok.com that proxies any requests sent to it to example.com port 8080. Then you can inspect the raw requests in ngrok's web monitoring UI, at http://localhost:4040. Needless to say, you will be sending all your data to a third party so do not submit any usernames and passwords you don't want to leak.

Answer (score 1):

`HTTPoison` runs on top of `hackney`. You can try the following to get more info about the stack and errors:

```
:hackney_trace.enable(:max, :io)
```

For example (talking to port 80 but server runs on different port):

```
[hackney trace 80 <0.264.0> 2022:09:16 16:35:47 4200] request                                                                               
   Content: [{module,hackney},                                                                                                              
             {line,313},                                                                                                                    
             {method,get},                                                                                                                  
             {url,{hackney_url,hackney_tcp,http,<<"localhost">>,                                                                            
                               <<"/api/test">>,                                                                  
                               <<"/api/test">>,                                                                  
                               <<>>,<<>>,"localhost",80,<<>>,<<>>}},                                                                        
             {headers,[{<<"Authorization">>,                                                                                                
                        <<"Bearer ...">>}]},                                                        
             {body,<<>>},                                                                                                                   
             {options,[]}]                                                                                                                  
[hackney trace 60 <0.264.0> 2022:09:16 16:35:47 4200] request without proxy                                                                 
   Content: [{module,hackney},{line,685}]                                                                                                   
[hackney trace 60 <0.264.0> 2022:09:16 16:35:47 4202] connect                                                                               
   Content: [{module,hackney_connect},                                                                                                      
             {line,32},                                                                                                                     
             {transport,hackney_tcp},                                                                                                       
             {host,"localhost"},                                                                                                            
             {port,80},                                                                                                                     
             {dynamic,true}]                                                                                                                
[hackney trace 80 <0.264.0> 2022:09:16 16:35:47 4205] no socket in the pool                                                                 
   Content: [{module,hackney_pool},{line,88},{pool,default}]                                                                                
[hackney trace 80 <0.264.0> 2022:09:16 16:35:47 4207] connect error                                                                         
   Content: [{module,hackney_pool},{line,108}]                                                                                              
[hackney trace 80 <0.264.0> 2022:09:16 16:35:47 4207] connect error                                                                         
   Content: [{module,hackney_connect},{line,233}]
```

See more on github/issues [here](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison/issues/302)